# Rock papers scissors

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I was trying to make  a program of rock papers scissors. But the for the output that I am getting is bot satisfactory.

```py
def rpc():
  import random
  moveset=["Rock","Paper","Scissors"]
  a=random.choice(moveset)
  "Rock">"Scissors","Scissors">"Paper","Paper">"Rock"
  playermove=input ("What will you play? please keep the first letter capital")
  print (a)
  if playermove == a:
    print ("draw")
  elif playermove>a:
    print("you win")
  elif playermove<a:
    print("you lose")
  else:
    print("no valid choice")
rpc()
rpc()
```

How should the code be modified?

Comment: Please include the code snippet in post instead of external links

Comment: `"Rock">"Scissors","Scissors">"Paper","Paper">"Rock"` doesn’t define anything, it’s just the tuple value `(False, True, False)`. You need to implement the comparison logic yourself.

Comment: @Ry- Well actually I am pretty new to programming and do it as a hobby, so i am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

as noted: your problem line is here:
  `"Rock">"Scissors","Scissors">"Paper","Paper">"Rock"`. This line doesn't actually do anything.

The other problem is here:
`elif playermove>a:` you are comparing two strings and your line from above is getting ignored.  To understand string comparison, try playing around with some strings and comparing them.  The comparison works like sorting by alphabetical order and capital letters are less than lowercase.

```
>>> "a" > "b"
False
>>> "ac" > "ab"
True
>>> "A" > "a"
False
>>> "A" > "z"
False
```

So you need to create a different test to check for winning an losing plays.  there are *many* ways to do this.  a simple test might be creating a list of winner_to_loser and seeing if your combination is in the list

```py
winner_loser = [('rock', 'scissors'), ('scissors', 'paper'), ('paper', 'rock')]
if (player_move, computer_move) in winner_loser:
    print("you win!")
elif (computer_move, player_move) in winner_loser:
   print("computer wins!")
```